JSON Path for element sometimes in an array
I need a JSON path to an "element" when the "condition" is 1
{
  "customer": [
    {
      "Addresses": {
        "addressDetails": {
          "element": "one"
        },
        "Condition": {
          "type": 1
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Addresses": [
        {
          "addressDetails": {
            "element": "two"
          },
          "Condition": {
            "type": 0
          }
        },
        {
          "addressDetails": {
            "element": "three"
          },
          "Condition": {
            "type": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
                                      

As you can see in the example: "Addresses" can sometimes be an array containing multiple details. I need to get the "element" of only those where the "Condition" is equal to 1 - so from this snippet the JSON path should return "one" and "three". Is that possible?
I tried many different ways with filtering using [?(@.==)] but it never worked - I only managed to get the element from either the non-array object or the array object, never both.

What you're looking for is the recursive descent operator ...  This will recursively search down the tree.  Start with that, and then you can use your filter [?...].
$..[?(@.Condition.type == 1)]

You can test this on my site: https://json-everything.net/json-path.

As a side note, with the new RFC 9535, you don't need the paretheses:
$..[?@.Condition.type == 1]

Note that since is a new spec, implementations are still catching up, so check with the library you're using.
